# Automatically Displaying the latest 5 videos for youtube in a html

Tags: html, json, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

[image: 1]I am trying to display the lastest five videos from my youtube channel on one HTML page. I have managed to successfully embed one youtube video with this code but I am unable to upload any other one. I have tried to embed the second latest video as well but no matter what I try, I get a playback error with invalid ID as seen above. Does anyone have a clue how I could embed the latest 5 videos from my YouTube Chanel in JSON/JavaScript?

Below is my code

```js
    var channelID = "MY-ID";
    var reqURL = "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=";
    $.getJSON("https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + encodeURIComponent(reqURL)+channelID, function(data) {
       var link = data.items[0].link;
       var id = link.substr(link.indexOf("=")+1);
    $("#youtube_video").attr("src","https://youtube.com/embed/"+ id + "?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0");
    });
```

```html
<iframe id="youtube_video" width="600" height="340" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you also include the error in your post?

Comment: @jess I have just added an image of the error

Answer (score 1):

I Found It you have to change the number in the []'s.

```js
   var channelID = "MY-ID";
    var reqURL = "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=";
    $.getJSON("https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + encodeURIComponent(reqURL)+channelID, function(data) {
       var link = data.items[0].link;
       var id = link.substr(link.indexOf("=")+1);
    $("#youtube_video").attr("src","https://youtube.com/embed/"+ id + "?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0");
  var link = data.items[1].link;
        var id = link.substr(link.indexOf("=")+1);
    $("#youtube_video2").attr("src","https://youtube.com/embed/"+ id + "?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0");
  var link = data.items[2].link;
      var id = link.substr(link.indexOf("=")+1);
    $("#youtube_video3").attr("src","https://youtube.com/embed/"+ id + "?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0");
 
    });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe id="youtube_video" width="600" height="340" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe id="youtube_video2" width="600" height="340" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe id="youtube_video3" width="600" height="340" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: That's great that you have fixed your issue.